# Loop for multiple database and user creation in SQL, assign user to the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

> ***after creating login using windows authentication ,
>            need to assign user to the database 
>            and provide permissions to that user.
>            Could anyone please help me with that. 
>           Thanks in advance.***

```
    -- BULK INSERT tempNames.dbo.tempNames
             --      FROM 'C:\Users\Videos\file.txt'
                --   WITH 
            --        (
                  --      ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'--
                    --  )

                USE [master]
                GO

                DECLARE @NameCursor as CURSOR;
                DECLARE @NAME AS NVARCHAR(50);
                DECLARE @NAME2 AS NVARCHAR(50);
                DECLARE @NIUNT AS NVARCHAR(50);

                SET @NIUNT ='niunt';

                SET @NameCursor = CURSOR FOR
                SELECT id
                 FROM test.dbo.Sheet1$

                OPEN @NameCursor;
                FETCH NEXT FROM @NameCursor INTO @Name;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                PRINT @Name
```

### Creating database  using @name

```
                set @name2 ='create database '+@Name + ';'

                  exec (@name2)

                  BEGIN
                    SET NOCOUNT ON
                    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
```

### Creating login using @name

```
                    SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN [' +@NIUNT +'\'+ @NAME + '] from windows';                    
                    exec(@SQL); 

                    -END;


                 FETCH NEXT FROM @NameCursor INTO @Name;

                 END 

                GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is awfully intricate.  It seems easier to operate directly upon the underlying system tables that actually represent the authentication and authorization data.  Then you won't have to muck about with cursors and such.

FOR EXAMPLE, let's say that logins were represented by a table, SYS$LOGINS, with fields SYS$USERNAME and SYS$PASSWORD.  Isn't it easier to just INSERT a record for user 'joe' into that table (let's not worry about the details of how encrypted passwords are stored: it's just a quick example!) than to have to define cursors, and construct SQL strings, and exec() them?

I should think you have to be the SYSTEM user to do all this, but I'm sure you already are.

Comment: @ Bruce David Wilner , yeah I am a system user and i gave all the names of database, users (same name as database) in a file. I need to fetch the names from that file and create db, users using loop. I am done withe creating db, users, but couldnt get how to assign the user to the particular database. Any suggestions in that part?